# Adding HTML tag to div in ASP.NET (VB)

Tags: asp.net

I have a text file containing the following HTML tags:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" width="500">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>some text</td>

<td>some text</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

I want to be able to load these HTML tags into `<div runat=server id=div1>`

Any idea on how to do it with ASP.NET? (VB code is preferred)

Comment: You can use a `<asp:Literal />` to do something like this.

Answer (score 1):

I probably wouldn't use .NET code to do all of this.  I would use jQuery to call either a service or page method that loads the contents of the text file.  You could return this through a jQuery asynchronous call and then set the innerHTML property of the div with the result.

*edit*

If you really wanted to do it on the server side, you could do something like this:

```
<div id="divTest" runat="server">

</div>


Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        divTest.InnerHtml = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fileName)
End Sub
```

Comment: The problem with jquery is that those changes are made only after page is shown to the client and I want to do it before the client get the page

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a better way but you can try this code:

```
Dim l As New Literal()
l.Text = "<table border=""0"" cellspacing=""2"" cellpadding=""2"" width=""500""><tbody><tr><td>some text</td><td>some text</td></tr></tbody></table>"

div1.Controls.Add(l)
```